# How to I access the request object when debugging with pry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, pry

I am trying to figure out what is going on in the admin/topics controller in the spree_easy contact gem.  There is this bit of code in the controller:

```
new_action.response do |wants|
  wants.html {render :action => :new, :layout => !request.xhr?}
end
```

And I want to see what the `request.xhr?` resolves to.  How would I access this using debugging with pry?

Comment: what wrong with placing binding.pry in the end of do block?

...!request.xhr?}
   binding.pry
end

Comment: `.xhr?` checks the presence of `header[X-Requested-With]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place it at the top:

```
binding.pry
new_action.response do |wants|
  wants.html {render :action => :new, :layout => !request.xhr?}
end
```

`request` is the same everywhere within the controller, so it doesn’t matter as long as the `binding.pry` gets called. Also, you can see the [implementation of `xhr?` on GitHub](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.9/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb#L146).

Comment: Ok so assuming I set my binding.pry call correctly and I enter into the debugger session correctly, what exactly do I type into the pry console to access the value of request.xhr ?

Comment: @RebekahWaterbury You type `request.xhr?`…